# How to give more bandwidth to my browser while it's playing video?

Tags: macos, networking

I don't have a really fast connection. When I'm playing a video on Youtube, my browser is competing with other process for bandwidth. I know the minimum bandwith required for the video to play correctly. Is there a way to allocate a certain amount of my bandwidth to the browser ?

Answer (score 0):

You may want to limit bandwidth of other [process or app](http://www.mymacosx.com/osx/bandwidth-throttling.html). I don't think there is a way to guarantee a certain bandwidth for a specific process.

Comment: According to the man page, ipfw is deprecated.

Comment: Right then use pf, `man pfctl` and `man pf.conf` for more info

Answer (score 0):

You could look at setting up QOS on your router if the application uses a specific port for its traffic.